# КОДИРОВКА текста с андроид приложения

Tags: кодировка

ЗДРАВСТВУЙТЕ, пытаюсь прочитать текстовый документ из папки assets анроид приложения.
Игра на португальском языке,
Когда я открываю текстовый файл через notepad++, то появляются непонятные символы
XXTEAГЕ‘Єp›яЎЦафмтєИЪ8ІM8b(МѓI—є+вXЁ0    ,МЁчъ¤9і2.„Dљй­ЃЪSћ›*m9T®(Ґ[*‡Ь®`HZщЌ)Аa+оH7}>њЃ­JgFЂPZl*є Д6’

"Љн¬иSя.®u—л""єО5«F€$аХCvЊ"

"“Ѕ„Hыпgћ†:yq‡ш4xэ3fЊЖy”з""е3‘_ҐIШ†”5""<yЬз5Mюtх»УyH<‹·l-&№]l(»„zxшuQ„ЧЇЛCg‰ќпЄЖ‘Кјі—4,’n|" ~EАp9Тісs)“ц1`<З®9¬‚[”weЬ}тLxоТ!‚±фЂ­ХбХR«ЊuuED   "гщW¦BRнёўИп”Пs|лт А}јФ.j`СdtNО'“я•оt)hњ^ДЦzј""–>ҐX™|ІЎ1ЋsЛЊ4W\0уЮHљVз””¶3" "iЬ‘<р[_7¦м#y®cҐp…aТяМkрЌЄе›n¬Ь<З  ±$ЁwhК:¦гбЄвб<БxwщBl©ѕZT' :„€лВXsjЄuЏ›ЩК¦bІrX…€–вfзҐ]jЦ‰gзЄ”љФІЂ¬юјђPwгkAХдs¤сЫЋ=FnT#ѓЃнгK”љ®Ййм&2m2цu:·№AZ¦С­ЮNРЁ±_‰”–™Мхѓ%А>ІЕsЬqDФZЙІіpы+‹ЙmВVВ…йI–ЯupRЎ3!г<9v›dxЮU{Ъї8іbDОл$9X»Џј•ЋМTvз…"

"йдрЂд·ЄБ~m!ОQХЩ•mўtЄ•#‰~=ЋfаЄ·}М%­вeIp—YЁл©    ]Я¦ХРk™ГХзrЅiнFъ•pX{%ЦЪ!W‚`Д|нфQ™`OJЩ›±ЩK'U1VЬ(lґMЁЙ8љlћZкЙ:‡јplО$љzQ€№"

Смена кодировки не помогает.
Подскажите, чем можно прочесть этот текст?

Comment: похоже на бинарные данные, а не текстовые. Мб это просто архив, а мб это зашифрованные данные

Comment: Вы уверены, что это именно текстовый файл?

Comment: файл формата csv

Comment: XXTEA — это название алгоритма симметричного шифрования, может ваш CSV-файл зашифрован?

Comment: СКОРЕЕ ВСЕГО ЗАШИФРОВАН

Comment: ЛИБО ЗАКОДИРОВАН, Я В ЭТОМ НЕ ОСОБО РАЗБИРАЮСЬ)))